# Slam valve pattern

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, language-agnostic

Something I've seen a sprinkling of times over the past few decades is slam valve type code where there is a contrived value which decrements/increments to force a loop to exit once a certain value has been breached or where a number of iterations have passed.

A bit abstract for you?

Some concrete examples:

**File read**

In this case, a file is being read in a data factory overnight so needs to be processed by a certain time in order for the system to be available in the morning. N.B. it doesn't matter if the file completes.

```
int linesRead = 0;

const int SillyAmount = 1000000;

while (!EOF)
{
    text = ReadLine();
    // Do Some complicated processing with the text
    linesRead++;

    if (linesRead > SillyAmount)
        break;
}
```

**Service conversation**

In this example an object is gradually enhanced via service calls until the data is good enough to be processed later on.

```
int conversationLines = 10;

while (conversationLines > 0 && conversation.Status != Complete)
{
    conversation.Next();
    // Process conversation
    conversationLines--;    
}
```

Questions.

(1) Is there a design pattern or similar for this sort of thing?

(2) In the absence of (1) and given that you're artificially exiting a loop, could this be deemed a code smell?

Comment: Well, Dijkstra would probably complain about the first one, but he complained about most things ;)  Using `break;` instead of confining all loop-exit conditions to the `while` expression makes it slightly harder to make guarantees about the state of the world on the first line of code after the loop, since you have to go through the loop body gathering up all the `break` possibilities and `||` them together.  But often, trying to jam all loop-exit conditions into the `while` expression makes things much more complicated.

Comment: "slam valve" is new.  I've always called that a limit.

Comment: I've always found people refer to these things as throttling (or rate-limiting if you're old-school) or chunking

Comment: I wouldn't call this a pattern, but rather a technique.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example could be written:

```
int linesRead = 0;
const int SillyAmount = 1000000;

do {
  text = ReadLine();
  // text processing
} while (!EOF && ++linesRead <= SillyAmount);
```

Which doesn't look like a hack anymore (no `break`). No pattern comes to mind for this one.

The second one leaves more to interpretation (would need a more complete example to really tell). We could argue that the conversation object should perhaps be designed as a [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) (see also the [state pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)) and process the conversation internally to prevent having such code out in the open. The actual processing to be done could be passed as a (reducing?) function, or using some kind of [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) implementation depending on predefined types of conversations. There are many ways to rearrange this. We'd need a more realistic example since this one is a little weird (conversation has the iterator (`conversation.Next();`) but the number of lines is outside... could just tell it to process up to a certain number `conversation.processUpTo(10);`?).